# Clarifications on $\mathcal S$-measurability and $\mu$-measurability

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $B$ be a Banach space and $(X, \mathcal S, \mu : \mathcal S \to [0, \infty])$ be a measured space. First, we define simple measurable functions and simple integrable functions as follows:

> **Definition 1** ($\mathcal S$-SMF). We say that a function $f: X \to B$ is $\mathcal S$-simple measurable function if the range of $f$ is finite and for nonzero $b$ in the range, $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ is measurable.
>
> **Definition 2** ($\mathcal S$-SIF). We say that a function $f: X \to B$ is $\mathcal S$-simple integrable function if it is a $\mathcal S$-SMF and each $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ has finite measure.

In my analysis class (taught by Professor Marc Rieffel), we defined the two measurability as follows:

> **Definition 3** (Rieffel, $\mathcal S$-measurability). A function $f : X \to B$ is $\mathcal S$-measurable if there is a sequence of $\mathcal S$-SMFs $f_n$ which converge pointwise to $f$.
>
> **Definition 4** (Rieffel, $\mu$-measurability). A function $f: X \to B$ is $\mu$-measurable if there is a sequence of (bounded?) $\mathcal S$-SMFs $f_n$ which converge pointwise almost everywhere to $f$.

In Lang's Real and Functional Analysis, from what I see, $\mathcal S$-SMF are called simple maps while $\mathcal S$-SIF are called step maps. The same concepts of measurability are defined somewhat differently as follows:

> **Definition 4** (Lang, $\mathcal S$-measurability). A function $f: X \to B$ is $\mathcal S$-measurable if for all open sets $O \subseteq B$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is measurable.
>
> **Definition 5** (Lang, $\mu$-measurability). A function $f: X \to B$ is $\mu$-measurable if it is a pointwise limit of a sequence of step maps almost everywhere.

I have several questions regarding these definitions. First, is there any necessity in excluding $0$ from the range? It seems as if $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ being measurable for each nonzero $b$ must imply $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ measurable as $$ f^{-1}(\{0\}) = X \setminus \left(\bigcup_b f^{-1}(\{b\})\right). $$

Second, it doesn't seem like the two definitions of $\mathcal S$-measurability are equivalent here. Specifically, in class, we proved the following equivalent formulation of Rieffel's $\mathcal S$-measurability:

> **Theorem 1** (Equivalent Rieffel $\mathcal S$-measurability).     A function $f : X \to B$ is $\mathcal S$-measurable if and only if
>
> - $\text{range}(f)$ is separable.
> - for all open sets $O \subseteq B$ with $0 \not \in O$, $f^{-1}(O)
>               \in \mathcal S$ i.e. $f^{-1}(O)$ is measurable.

and there are some obvious differences between this and Lang's $\mathcal S$-measurability. Interestingly, Lang points out a similar result in his book, which states that for $B$ a finite dimensional space, $f$ is Lang $\mathcal S$-measurable if and only if $f$ is the pointwise limit of simple maps, which shows that the two definitions should be equivalent in this finite dimensional case. However, it would be nice if someone could clear up precisely what the differences are and why they're affecting the results (i.e. the equivalences in the definitions as pointwise limits vs $f^{-1}$ preserving measurability).

Third, it seems like I have something incorrect in the definition of Rieffel's $\mu$-measurability, as I wrote down in my notes the word "bounded" while Lang simply states that we wish to use sequences of step maps (or SIFs, as I call them). I would also like a clarification on this.

Finally, exactly what is the relationship between $\mathcal S$-measurability and $\mu$-measurability? The former seems like it defines what morphisms should be between measurable spaces, while the latter seems like it is a definition of how we want to integrate functions. They seem like they have some important differences, but they are also called by the same name.

Comment: The equation you have for $f^{-1} (\{0\})$ proves nothing because it has an uncountable union. It is important to avoid $f^{-1} (\{0\})$ in the definition. Separability is required for equivalence of the two notion of measurability. $f$ is $\mu$- measurable iff there is a set $E$ of measure $0$ such that $f(E^{c})$ is separable and there exist simple functions converging a.e. to $f$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: It is not really an uncountable union, since the range of $f$ is assumed to be finite, so that $f^{-1}(\{b\}) = \emptyset$ for all but finitely many $b$. I think the argument of the OP is correct; it always follows that $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is measurable as well. I think the reason why this is stated this way is that the customary way of writing down a simple function is $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j 1_{A_j}$ with the $A_j$ measurable and the $a_j$ pairwise distinct. Here, one does not want to be forced to include the term for $a_j = 0$ always.

Comment: As far as I can see, the value $b=0$ should be excluded from the finiteness-of-measure requirement in Definition 2, not in Definition 1.